# error when cargo build node-templare with Pallet in its own Crate

Tags: substrate

I followed the [Write a Pallet in its Own Crate](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-a-pallet/) tutorial.
I doublechecked everything with the tutorial but when I `cargo build --release`, I get 66 error messages. Most of these error messages are like the following 2 (more details further down):

```
    cannot find type `Pallet` in crate/scope
    the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Congig` is not satisfied
```

I created an error-log. what is the best way to post the error log or so many error messages here on stackoverflow.com?

```
Information that should be included in a bug report.
Executing build command: "/home/df/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"
Using rustc version: rustc 1.55.0-nightly (24bdc6d73 2021-06-12)
```

The first error displayed is the following:

```
  errorm: expected one of: `Pallet`, `Call`, `Storage`, `Event`, `Config`, `Origin`, `Inherent`, `ValidateUnsigned`
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:338:29
      |
  338 |         TestPallet: test_pallet::{Module, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
      |                                   ^^^^^^ `
```

Thus I removed `Module` from line 338: `TestPallet: test_pallet::{Module, Call, Storage, Event<T>},`

If I `cargo build --release` again, I get 14 error messages which I post below. Do you have any Idea, what goes wrong?

```
   Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-10b4571a8bd12437/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "/home/df/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.55.0-nightly (24bdc6d73 2021-06-12)


  --- stderr
     Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Pallet` in crate `test_pallet`
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ not found in `test_pallet`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: consider importing one of these items
      |
  9   | use crate::pallet_template::Pallet;
      |
  9   | use frame_system::Pallet;
      |
  9   | use pallet_aura::Pallet;
      |
  9   | use pallet_balances::Pallet;
      |
        and 7 other candidates

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-68d2ddc13c0ddd99.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0c3d7ed5f1bed9c8.rmeta

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `oom`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-68d2ddc13c0ddd99.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-0c3d7ed5f1bed9c8.rmeta

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:316:6
      |
  316 | impl test_pallet::Config for Runtime {
      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      | 
     ::: /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/pallets/test-pallet/src/lib.rs:17:19
      |
  17  | pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
      |                   -------------------- required by this bound in `test_pallet::Config`

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Event: TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not implemented for `Event`
      |
      = help: the following implementations were found:
                <Event as TryInto<frame_system::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_balances::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_grandpa::Event>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_nicks::RawEvent<AccountId32, u128>>>
              and 3 others
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Event: TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not implemented for `Event`
      |
      = help: the following implementations were found:
                <Event as TryInto<frame_system::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_balances::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_grandpa::Event>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_nicks::RawEvent<AccountId32, u128>>>
              and 3 others
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Event: TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
      |
  321 | / construct_runtime!(
  322 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  323 | |         Block = Block,
  324 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  340 | |     }
  341 | | );
      | |__^ the trait `TryInto<test_pallet::RawEvent<_>>` is not implemented for `Event`
      |
      = help: the following implementations were found:
                <Event as TryInto<frame_system::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_balances::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_grandpa::Event>>
                <Event as TryInto<pallet_nicks::RawEvent<AccountId32, u128>>>
              and 3 others
      = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::impl_outer_event` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error: aborting due to 14 previous errors

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0412.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime`

  To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to add `pub use pallet::*;` in your test-pallet/lib.rs

Answer (score 0):

You should **replace** `Module` with `Pallet`, instead of removing it.

Comment: Hi kianenigma, thanks for your answer, but it does not solve the error. I tried what you suggested:
```
construct_runtime!(
    // --snip--
    TestPallet: test_pallet::{**Pallet**, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
```
`cargo build --release` results in 15 errors: 14 from before and the following one:
```
 error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Pallet` in `test_pallet`
    --> /mnt/f/Etp/Substrate/tutorials/02/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:321:1
     |
// skip
     ||__^could not find `Pallet` in `test_pallet`
     |
```